# How do I install Linux as a third OS alongside Windows 7 and Windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-7, windows-10, boot

I currently have dual-boot with Windows 7 and Windows 10, although I'm not sure they boot correctly.

If I previously booted Windows 7, the next boot I get a black & white, DOS-looking boot menu. If I previously booted Windows 10, I have the newer, blue, aesthetic GUI boot menu.

I'd like to add a Linux partition too. Last time I ran the Linux installer, it could only detect one of the Windows partitions and I was worried about proceeding and not being able to boot in to the other Windows partition.

What's the best way to proceed with this?

Comment: Certainly not an answer to your question (thus the comment).  I fought this for quite some time as I need to support multiple operating systems. "Back in the day" before UEFI and BCD.. I could install a 3rd party boot loader with ease and accomplish this.  VMs are your friend and offer close to zero performance degradation these days.  They also offer things the raw boot can't like snapshots and rollback.  I would highly suggest that you change your strategy but I do hope someone comes along and helps you. :)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately I don't think I can use VMs as I will be doing profiling work and require access to the Intel CPU counters (I'm sure they're not accessible through a VM).

Comment: Are you [sure](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-F920A3C7-3B42-4E78-8EA7-961E49AF479D.html) about that?  I didn't look at VirtualBox.. but it is probably similar.  I myself would host from Linux and run Windows VMs.. but I digress.

Answer (score 0):

Use any Linux Distro that have a bootloader that supports Windows Bootloader (like GRUB). Most distro use it by default though.

Just install Linux with GRUB and *in theory* GRUB should detect the Windows Bootloader by default.
If it doesn't detect Windows 7, check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/198875/1476180)

Be extra safe and backup your data before doing this though. Bad things happen if you did something wrong.